# Write data in one row using csv

Tags: python, excel, csv

I want to make excel file using csv :

```
writer = csv.writer(proxy, dialect='excel', delimiter='\t')
```

data = ['1','2','3','4']

I want my excel like:

1    |   2     |   3    |   4    |

but now my excel :

1

2

3

4

My code :

```
for x in data:
   writer.writerow([x])
```

what should i do to make it in one row only

Comment: Don't set `delimiter='\t'` if you're trying to create a CSV.  Excel imports the normal comma separators just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a loop.

```
writer.writerow(data)
```

### Followup

Here's an example.

```
timr@tims-gram:~/src$ cat x.py
import csv
writer = csv.writer(open('x.csv','w'), dialect='excel', delimiter='\t')
data = ['1','2','3','4']
writer.writerow(data)
timr@tims-gram:~/src$ python x.py
timr@tims-gram:~/src$ cat x.csv
1   2   3   4
timr@tims-gram:~/src$
```

Comment: I try not using loop but data won't separated cause i want one cell have one data

Comment: Of course it will be separated.  `writerow` expects to get a list.  It will put one list item in each "cell".

Comment: aw there's typo on my code. THX

Answer (score 0):

Excel includes a TRANSPOSE() function that takes an array & changes a vertical column of values to horizontal rows.
Since the file is a CSV, Excel should be able to open the file and read in the values.

You might be able to select the upper left most cell and select the range, and run TRANSPOSE.